# iOS7 PhoneGap Freezing after using ZBar Scanner

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, zbar-sdk

I have a PhoneGap app that uses the ZBar scanning plugin in iOS.  It allows me to use the scanner a few times, but after a few tries, the next click on the scan button to invoke the plugin causes the app freeze for anywhere between 30 seconds and 5 minutes.  Then it will resume normal function again.

It only happens on devices when iOS7 is installed.  I have tested this.

I've noticed that xcode gives me an output message of "Received memory warning".  It might be related somehow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/patches/36/) issue, the `ZBarReaderViewController`'s `view` property is retained and therefore leaks.

As stated in the ZBar SDK documentation [here](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html#integrate-the-reader), when you initialise the `ZBarReaderViewController` set the reader's view property to `autorelease`:

```
- (IBAction) scanButtonTapped
{
    // ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];

    // Fixes memory leak for the view property.
    [reader.view autorelease];

    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    // TODO: (optional) additional reader configuration here

    // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
             config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
             to: 0];

    // present and release the controller
    [self presentModalViewController: reader
          animated: YES];
    [reader release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I added the [reader.view autorelease]; line in and it seems to work fine.